# Avoid retain count with __block variable with block method like in FMDatabaseQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb

i'm using FMDatabaseQueue, and i don't want retain count using __block variable, because i have a method with a return value, that is the result of the read of the database, this is an example:

```
- (BOOL)existProduct:(int)id_product
{
    __block BOOL exist = NO;

    [self.dbQueue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

        FMResultSet *pr_query = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT id FROM product WHERE id_product = ?",[NSNumber numberWithInt:id_product]];

        while ([pr_query next]) {

            exist = YES;
        }
    }];

    return exist;
}
```

the documentation says this:

> As described, instead, you can use a __block qualifier and set the myController variable to nil in the completion handler

```
MyViewController * __block myController = [[MyViewController alloc] init…];
// ...
myController.completionHandler =  ^(NSInteger result) {
    [myController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    myController = nil;
};
```

but i can't put `exist = nil`, because is my return value, so how i can solve this problem?

EDIT: In some cases i have object and not primitive variable to return value like this:

```
- (Product *)searchProduct:(int)id_product
    {
        __block Product *prod = nil;

        [self.dbQueue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

            FMResultSet *pr_query = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM product WHERE id_product = ?",[NSNumber numberWithInt:id_product]];

            while ([pr_query next]) {

                prod = [[Product alloc] init]
                prod.id = ...
                ...
            }
        }];

        return prod;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the issue? `exists` is a primitive type (`BOOL`). Primitive types don't get retained or released or deallocated.

Your first block of code is fine as-is.

Though you can change your `while` to an `if` since you only want to know if there is any data. No need to iterate all of the results.

Comment: thanks for your answer, in some case i have object to return and not only primitive, i have update my question

Comment: It's still not an issue in the first block of code, even if the return value isn't a primitive type. Your second example is a problem due to a reference cycle. But the first block doesn't have a reference cycle.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have update again the question, i doesn't have any problem also with that code? the prod object is not retained?

Comment: The code appears fine assuming you are using ARC. If you want to be sure, use the Allocations tool of Instruments and see if any `Product` instances are left as a result of the call to `searchProduct:`.

Comment: @Piero your original concern was due to a misreading of the arc transition notes.  That doc suggests using a __block qualifier (and nilling it later) when referring to the **owner** of the block, in order to break a retain cycle.  The variables you're worried about don't own the block, they are just results of the block.